# I have been searching solution for this but still having error in my update query at the time of image upload

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

This is my update button click event:

```
 private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ValidateAll())
                {
                    SetValues();
                    _objHotel_EL.HotelID = HotelId;
                    _objHotel_EL.CommandName = "Update_HotelDetails";

                    int update = _objHotel_BL.Insert_Hotel(_objHotel_EL);

                    if (update > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Hotel Details Updated");
                        ClearAll();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Already Exists");
                        ClearAll();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

here's my code which is used to set and upload image and other parameters:

```
private void SetValues()
        {
            _objHotel_EL.HotelName = txtHotelName.Text.Trim();
            _objHotel_EL.PhoneNo = txtPhoneNo.Text.Trim();
            _objHotel_EL.Address = txtAddress.Text.Trim();
            _objHotel_EL.EmailId = txtEmailId.Text.Trim();
            _objHotel_EL.WebSite = txtWebsite.Text.Trim();
            _objHotel_EL.CurrID = CommanValue.CurrID;

            if (flag == 1)
            {
                _objHotel_EL.BinaryImage = ReadFile(labelImagePath.Text);
                _objHotel_EL.ImagePath = labelImagePath.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                if (imageData == null)
                {
                    string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\\Debug", "");
                    path = path.Replace("\\bin", "");
                    path = path.Replace("\\x86", "");
                    path = path + "Images\\NoImage1.png";
                    labelImagePath.Text = path;
                    imageData = ReadFile(labelImagePath.Text);
                    _objHotel_EL.ImagePath = path;
                }
                _objHotel_EL.ImagePath = labelImagePath.Text;
                _objHotel_EL.BinaryImage = (byte[])imageData;
            }
        }
```

This is code of ReadFile:

```
 private byte[] ReadFile(string strPath)
        {
            byte[] data = null;
            FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(strPath);
            long numBytes = fInfo.Length;
            FileStream fstream = new FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
            data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
            return data;
        }
```

Please help me out because its giving me an error `The conversion is not supported. [ Type to convert from (if known) = nvarchar, Type to convert to (if known) = image ]` while i am using sql server compact in visual studio 2012 using c#.

In database side datatype of image is image.

Comment: What is returned type of your *ReadFile* function?

Comment: show code for ReadFile Method

Comment: i have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I tried with myself after using `SqlCeCommand` parameters and its solved.
Here is the code.

```
if (objEL.CommandName == "Update_HotelDetails")
            {
                DataTable dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset("SELECT HotelName, HotelID FROM Master_Hotel WHERE (HotelName = '" + objEL.HotelName + "') AND (HotelID <> '" + objEL.HotelID + "')").Tables[0];
                if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    string str = ("UPDATE Master_Hotel SET HotelName = @HotelName, PhoneNo = @PhoneNo, Address = @Address, EmailId = @EmailId, Website = @Website, Image = @Image,ImagePath = @ImagePath WHERE (HotelID = @HotelID)");

                    cmd = new SqlCeCommand(str, SqlHelper.objCon);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@HotelName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = objEL.HotelName;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = objEL.PhoneNo;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = objEL.Address;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = objEL.EmailId;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Website", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = objEL.WebSite;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = objEL.BinaryImage;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ImagePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = objEL.ImagePath;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@HotelID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = objEL.HotelID;
                    SqlHelper.objCon.Open();
                    i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    SqlHelper.objCon.Close();
                }
            }
```